# Memory allocation when push and pop the Navigation view

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, instruments, allocation

For first screen I have `UITableViewController` and after selecting the row, I push new `ViewController`. Both are placed inside `UINavigationViewController`.

[image]

I try to test my memory usage with `Instruments : Allocations : Mark Generations`
All I did was :

```
1. Mark Generations
2. Click on cell
3. Click back 
4. Repeat step 1.
```

The logical conclusion would be that For each generation, (except for the first time) the Growth should be 0. (Because I return to the same screen) Or if there is a memory leak, the growth should be the same for all generations.
I know that this is idealistic view, so I expect some small deviations from this scenario.

But, what I get is something like this:

[image]

(The real generations are E, G, I, L, other are only to be sure that it fall down to 0)

The differences are quite huge.

The first time it was 20MB, second time 4MB, than 300KB, than 1.7MB,...
Is this normal behaviour? Is this due to some iOS cashing? Or it is a memory leak that is not the same all the time?

I look in this generations and always all the growth is done by

```
<non-object>
```